# Color Coding Lotus Notes 8.5 Calendar by Chair

Tags: colors, calendar, lotus-notes

Is it possible to assign a color to the Chair of the meeting in the Lotus Notes calendar? I'd like to color code the meetings in the calendar this way for quick reference.

Answer (score 0):

Without having actually done it I would say that it is possible.
But the mail template has to be changed, which needs advanced experience with domino applications.